# Apps crushes on emulators with android 4.3

Tags: android

I have an app i want to test on emulators with android versions 4+.

When the app starts, the emulators shuts down and the logcat displays the error below.

```
07-07 12:36:39.075: E/OpenGLRenderer(828): Error while compiling shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  Version number not supported by GL2
07-07 12:36:39.103: E/eglCodecCommon(828): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
```

The app works well on emulators with android 2.3.

Here is the entry in the manifest.

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

What is the cause?

Ronald

Comment: Have you specified a EGL version anywhere inside your app?

Comment: It looks like you're using openGL3 and its using 2.

Comment: I have not specified EGL version in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

This is Android Emulator Problem
i will suggest you to download Genymotion instead of default
it is very fast  and bugs free